# phantomjs cannot open url

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am not having any luck getting Phantomjs to access a url in my Selenium webdriver tests. I continue to get the following error after the assert -

```
Expected :Login
Actual   :403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at
```

Here is my - Also HTML Unit Driver does the same thing. However when I use Firefox driver it runs fine.

```
public class EasyElectPhantomTest {

private WebDriver driver;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
private String baseUrl;

@Before

public void setUp() throws Exception {
driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
baseUrl = "https://secure02.pilot.principal.com/";

@Test
public void testEasyElectPhantom() throws Exception {

driver.get(baseUrl + "/login?token=ODEFIJMLEHGIOPRNGIYN");
driver.manage().window().maximize();  //Maximizing window
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

assertEquals("Login", driver.getTitle());

driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys("Ryan");
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have?

Comment: In my maven project I have the 1.20 version dependency set with the Selenium-java 2.43 dependency

Comment: There is no such PhantomJS version. What groupId and artefactId is this?

Comment: Here is the dependency in maven project
     <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
   <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>

Comment: That is the PhantomJSDriver package version. I asked about your PhantomJS version (1.9.x or 2?).

Comment: version 2 is what I have downloaded